# Saving UITextView Text to Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I was wondering how to save the text inside UITextView to parse. Everytime I run my code below an error comes up saying it accidentally "found nil when unwrapping an optional" on the lines that save the information to parse.

Note: The functions "SaveNotesParse" and "SaveFrontScreenInfo" are where the errors occur. They are also both called in another class.

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleText: UITextView!



@IBOutlet weak var descriptionText: UITextView!



@IBOutlet weak var titleText2: UITextView!



@IBOutlet weak var contentText: UITextView!



let testObject = PFObject(className: "Notes")







func SaveNotesParse () {

    //parse stuff

    testObject["Title2"] = titleText2.text

    testObject["Content"] = contentText.text

    print("Saving")



    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        print("Object has been saved.")

    }



}



func SaveFrontScreenInfo () {

    testObject["Title"] = titleText.text

    testObject["Description"] = descriptionText.text

}




override func awakeFromNib() {



    foregroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    foregroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true



    super.awakeFromNib()

}



override func animationDuration(itemIndex:NSInteger, type:AnimationType)-> NSTimeInterval {



    let durations = [0.26, 0.2, 0.2]

    return durations[itemIndex]

}
```

Image of the error and line that it appears:

[Line that the error message appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOwdA.png)

[The actual error message as shown in the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6ft2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setObject function like so:

```
testObject.setObject(titleText2.text, forKey: "Title2")
```

Otherwise, can you tell us what is nil? It will have to be either the testObject or the Text Fields. Try printing them to see which one is nil.

Comment: I tried your solution, and the same error comes up. I have added photos of the error in my question above. Please note that the error happens on the line that it does since it is the first to execute, but the same error persists for all the other similar lines. Thanks.

Comment: just by the way, I think that the textview is what is coming up as nil despite the fact that there is text inside it.

Comment: Are you sure the IBOutlets are connected to the elements in the storyboard?

Comment: yeah they are definitely connected. I think the reason for the issue is because I am using a custom class that does not support UI. Thanks for the help though.